# why isn't my python loop iterating? it works if gcd is = a or b but it doesn't iterate

Tags: python, while-loop

a, b: positive integers
returns: a positive integer, the greatest common divisor of a & b.

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
 
    if a < b:
        gcd = a
    else: 
        gcd = b
    while gcd > 0:
        if a % gcd != 0 and  b % gcd != 0:
            gcd -= 1
        else:
            return gcd
print(gcdIter(9, 12))
```

Comment: did you try to debug it step by step and see what happens ?

Comment: Because `9%9` is `0` so the control goes to `else` condition which returns `9`

Comment: The logic seems convoluted. Why not use the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: @JohnColeman i havent gotten to that part of the python course yet

Comment: @Rabinzel i did but it skips over to the else part

Comment: That's wrong, it doesn't skip the else part.

Comment: Of course it skips *to* the `else:` part because one of the conditions in the `if` part will always fail.

Comment: This is a simple logic problem. Please carefully think about the line `if a % gcd != 0 and  b % gcd != 0:`. Consider what happens if `a` is equal to 9, `b` is equal to 12, and `gcd` is equal to `9`.

Comment: I was reading it skips the else part. My fault. Yes it skips to the else and then returns immediately

Comment: @quamrana do you have close votes left today? Please use /questions/2168603/de-morgans-rules-explained. There's also /questions/26337003/why-does-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-return-tr but it's harder to apply in this case (because "variable" and "value" are the wrong way around, though it doesn't matter).

Comment: Ok, let me just check those links ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is attempting to find GCDs in a brute force fashion by starting with the smaller of the two numbers and then working down to the GCD. This isn't efficient, but should work. Your code decrements `gcd` if it isn't a divisor of both. You need to decrement it if it isn't a divisor of either. To do this, swap `and` for `or`:

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
 
    if a < b:
        gcd = a
    else: 
        gcd = b
    while gcd > 0:
        if a % gcd != 0 or b % gcd != 0:
            gcd -= 1
        else:
            return gcd
print(gcdIter(9, 12))
```

Which prints `3`.

Having said all that, a dramatically more efficient approach is to study and implement the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
    if b>a:
        a,b=b,a
    while b:
        a,b = b,a%b
    return a

print(gcdIter(20,5))
```